# Difference between PreAuthroize and access

Tags: spring, spring-security

I use Spring MVC with Spring Security. I have this in my security XML:

```
<security:form-login 
        login-processing-url="/login/j_spring_security_check" 
        default-target-url="/home"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="failureHandler"
        login-page="/login"
/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/Queue/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" /> 
<bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="useReferer" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

When I call this URL:

```
/Queue/Home.html
```

I properly get redirected to the login page, I login, and then I am redirected back to `/Queue/Home.html`.

However, when I try the same thing with my controller and the `@PreAuthorize` annotation like this:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/Queue")
public class QueueController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showQueue(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession sess, ModelMap model) {
       .....  brilliant code
       return "some string";
    }
```

I get redirected properly to the login page, I then login,  but then I get redirected to

```
 /Queue/login
```

and given a message that that page does not exists  (Because it's doesn't).

Is there something else I have to do to get the `@PreAuthorize` to use the `successRedirectHandler`?

Comment: Is your question about the redirection to login page or about the wrong URL? Do you know, why your call is redirected to login page?

Comment: The Wrong URL.  I want to save a url,  got back to the url, login, then be redirected to the original url.  BUT  I can;t do that in the intercept-url part of the xml for various reasons.

Comment: @dur  Sorry for the confusion.  The correct login page is /login/login.  I have added the from-login part of the security xml.

Comment: Did you configure a access denied handler?